# Login and download all documents - Dropbox

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

Is it possible to give[**parameters**] username and password for **Dropbox** in python to download all documents in the disk ?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it's possible**

if you prefer using dropbox api

follow this :

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/python#downloading

For single file download

```
client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(access_token)
f, metadata = client.get_file_and_metadata('/my_file.txt')
out = open('my_file.txt', 'wb')
out.write(f.read())
out.close()
print metadata
```

You can do it for all files using documentation provided at link

also you can use selenium web driver for this

refer this:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html

Comment: Got an sample codes? Dropbox's PythonSDK requesting for app_key and app_secret.

Comment: The access_token might be requesting for OAuth. I'm interested to give username and password only.

Comment: @jOSe yes it's OAuth token that you have to get by providing app_key and app_secret

Comment: Can't we do like giving username and password in browser?

Comment: Uh oh, as per dropbox's documentation there's only one way but if thats the case then you can write a small selenium webdriver script which will open the browser and then open url fill in the username and password then login   and then do iterative download

Comment: Do you have any sample codes for selenium, respective with Dropbox?

Comment: No, With respective to dropbox I don't have . But I don't think It'll be very difficult to write one as there are many other examples available even the docs link is very good

Comment: I would prefer using APIs though

Comment: Okay I'll try to read Selenium. I too prefer API, but my scope is different.

Comment: Note that the Dropbox API does not offer a way to get an access token by directly supplying user credentials (i.e., email and password). Instead, apps should only use the OAuth flow, and never directly handle user credentials. Also, the terms disallow scraping: https://www.dropbox.com/terms#acceptable_use

Comment: @Greg i don't think automating user inputs is scraping, thoughts ?